# What is the priority mechanism in proxy settings of Internet Explorer browser

Tags: proxy

In Internet Explorer, below are the 3 proxy settings that can be set
1) auto proxy (automatically detect settings)
2) pac ( use automatic configuration script)
3) Manual Proxy

If all above are selected and correct values are passed, which setting will be picked by the browser?
e.g. if auto and pac are selected will auto proxy will be picked and pac will be ignored?
If auto proxy is selected and manual proxy settings are also provided, which proxy setting will browser pick?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for the future people out there coming across this, the settings are taken in the order they appear in the dialog: automatic, PAC configuration script, and then, manual proxy settings.

See the **Proxy Configurations** section of the [this MDSN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/10/11/understanding-web-proxy-configuration/). Specifically, the **Settings Precedence: Part 2** note.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on my research, if you check both the "Automatically Detect Settings" and "Automatic Configuration Script" boxes, auto-detection takes precedence, regarding auto-configuration and manual proxy server, the automatic configurations will take precedence over manual configuration.

Quoted from: [MSDN Forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a92d8eb9-bb21-4b16-afd4-ea9581b7b882/ie-proxy-setting-selection-orderpriority?forum=w7itprogeneral)